# ibm-db 3.2.0 ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, db2

Installed ibm-db 3.2.0 in Python 3.11.4.

Tried to import the package installed using the script below. Ran it in Visual Studio Code.

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
```

However, it is keep giving the following message.

```
>> import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import ibm_db_dbi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 45, in <module>
    import ibm_db
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.
```

The same situation doesn't happen on other packages installed at the same timeframe. Only the ibm-db has this issue.

Can anyone help please?

Reinstalling of ibm-db tried. Tried to install ibm-db in Python 3.10. The same situation is still happening.

The purpose of doing so is - to export the query result of db2 database into a Python dataframe straight away. This is the end outcome I expect. This needs to be done without exporting the result into a spreadsheet.

Comment: This is frequently asked.  Plase edit your question to add exactly how you installed ibm_db,  specifically, was the optional environment-variable IBM_DB_HOME already set __before__ you ran `pip install ibm_db`?,  and also specify if you ran the installation in an elevated (administrator mode) command window.

Comment: I restarted the ibm_db installation entirely. IBM_DB_HOME was set to IBM_DB_HOME=C:\Program\IBM\SQLLIB. Then install again pip install ibm_db.  in the admin mode, followed by the procedure you suggested below. It worked.

Comment: if the answer helped you, consider marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to work-around this symptom, which is often caused by the a DLL file not being present on the PATH , although better coding in the ibm_db setup would fix it.

The ibm_db module is a small wrapper around an external Db2 odbc driver, and that driver has many DLL files one of which is the main CLI dll (db2cli*.dll).

By default, when you install ibm_db, it will also install a small Db2 odbc driver called "clidriver".

If you used defaults when installing ibm_db, you will see clidriver directory in the "site-packages" location.  For example, you can use in a cmd.exe window `pip show ibm_db` to show the site-packages "Location:" (the full path), and under that location you can see clidriver sub-directory and under clidriver is the bin directory.

The clidriver\bin directory needs to be on the PATH when you python script runs, and when it is not on the PATH, your symptom is the result.

You can either manually add its bin directory to the PATH permanently, or you can alter your python-script to make the PATH change temporarily active while your python script runs. Sometimes the PATH variable value is too long for the default of Microsoft Windows (and a registry variable change to allow a longer PATH value is necessary), and sometimes previous manual edits to the PATH value have messed it up in such a way that it becomes invalid.

In your python script you can add code **before** you import the ibm_db module,  and you need to change 'your_clidriver_path\bin' (shown in the example below) into the fully qualified pathname of your clidriver\bin directory that you can see in the "Location:" reported by `pip show ibm_db`.

```
import os

os.add_dll_directory('your_clidriver_path\bin') 

import ibm_db
```

Sometimes there are additional dependencies, which require an additional directory on the PATH, this can vary with the installation of the Microsoft-Windows and the python ibm_db [README](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) gives more workarounds.